# oAuth multiple return url

Tags: facebook, oauth

I am doing oAuth logins on my site. When I am doing facebook, I found I can dynamically give a return urls. but when I am doing google, I found the return url I pass to google must match the settings I did on google.

Why it is different in both oauth providers, how about other oath providers?

What is the best way to implement dynamic return url?

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to the redirect uri in OAuth 2.0

From RFC 6749 (The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework):

> The authorization server MUST require the following clients to register their redirection endpoint:
>
> - Public clients.
> - Confidential clients utilizing the implicit grant type.
>
> The authorization server SHOULD require all clients to register their redirection endpoint prior to utilizing the authorization endpoint.

The "redirection endpoint" is the redirect uri.

Any client that uses the authorization code flow together with a client id and client secret can allow the user to specify the redirect uri. This is because the authorization code which is passed on to the redirect uri is useless unless you also have the client secret.

If the client isn't able to keep a secret and uses the implicit access token flow, e.g. a javascript only web application, the redirect uri has to be registered to make sure that the access token doesn't fall into the wrong hands.

OAuth providers can also choose to require the redirect uri to be registered even when using the authorization code flow as an extra security measure.

As for implementing dynamic redirect uri that depends on the library you're using for oauth on your site.

Comment: Yes, to implement multiple return uris, I can use static redirect uri set in oAuth server, and redirect again based on session in my server.

However, I am just curious why facebook oauth itself allow multiple return uris, but google oauth doesn't.